# Node.js / Redis / Socket.IO performance issues

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, node-redis

My application is as follows

Node.js with Express , cluster , express , redis , RedisStore etc

The redisclient listens to channels in redis and emits to sockets and this happens at a high rate . 
I am also using the redisstore . I am pasting the server code and a redisconnection class at bottom for clarity

The issue is that after the server starts up and after serving a few requests ,
I get couple of exception like EPIPE which are handled and few warnings like

warn  - client not handshaken client should reconnect

and then nodejs completly hangs up

Node version  - 0.8.21

I have pasted the entire section of server.js , I would like to know if there are any mistakes in the way things are configured and if that can cause any performance issues.

Any help is appreciated

```
var express = require('express'),
config = require('./services/resource/config.js'),
routeprocess = require('./services/routeprocess/routeprocess.js'),
socketevent = require('./socketevent'),
cluster = require('cluster'),
RedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis')
redis  = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis')
numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

var channels=['XXXXXXXXXXXX','YYYYYYYYYYY','ZZZZZZZZ','AAAAAAAAA','BBBBBBBBBBB','CCCCCCCCCCCC'];

app = express();
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/web',{ maxAge: 2592000000 }));
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/web'));
app.use(app.router);
app.use(function(req, res){
   res.sendfile(__dirname + '/web/'+ req.url );
});

app.use(function(err,req,res,next) {
    console.log(err);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/web/'+ 'index.html' );
});

app.all('/rest/storegraphsummary/:code?', function (req, res) {
    console.log("/rest/summary/ "+req.params.code);
   routeprocess.onStoreGraphSummary(req, res, req.params.storeCode);
});



if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i=0;i<numCPUs;i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
}
else{
    var http = require('http');
    http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 10000;
    server = http.createServer(app);
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

    redisPub    = redis.createClient(config.rDisServer.port,config.rDisServer.host)
    redisSub    = redis.createClient(config.rDisServer.port,config.rDisServer.host)
    redisclient = redis.createClient(config.rDisServer.port,config.rDisServer.host);
    nodeJSRedisclient = redis.createClient(config.rDisServer.port,config.rDisServer.host);

    io.set('store', new RedisStore({
      redis    : redis
    , redisPub : redisPub
    , redisSub : redisSub
    , redisClient : nodeJSRedisclient
    }));

    io.set('log level', 1);                    
    io.set('transports', [
            'websocket'
          , 'flashsocket'
          , 'htmlfile'
          , 'jsonp-polling'
          ]);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socketevent.listner(socket);
    socket.on('error', function (exc) {
         console.log("ignoring exception: " + exc);
    });
    });


    redisclient.on("connect", function() {
        channels.forEach(function(channel){
            redisclient.subscribe(channel);
        });   
    });   

    redisclient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        if(channel== 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'){
             io.sockets.emit(channel + ':' + JSON.parse(message)['orderNo'] , JSON.parse(message));       
        }else{
             io.sockets.emit(channel, JSON.parse(message));       
        }
    }); 

    redisPub.on("error", function (err) { 
         console.log("Redis connection error to " + redisPub.host + ":" + redisPub.port + " - " + err); 
     });

    redisSub.on("error", function (err) { 
         console.log("Redis connection error to " + redisSub.host + ":" + redisSub.port + " - " + err); 
     });

    redisclient.on("error", function (err) { 
         console.log("Redis connection error to " + redisclient.host + ":" + redisclient.port + " - " + err); 
     });

    nodeJSRedisclient.on("error", function (err) { 
         console.log("Redis connection error to " + nodeJSRedisclient.host + ":" + nodeJSRedisclient.port + " - " + err); 
     });
    server.listen(process.argv[2]); 
}       

cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
   // if (this.isMaster) {
        var newWorker = cluster.fork();
        console.log('worker ' + newWorker.process.pid + ' born');
   // }    
});

cluster.on('listening', function (worker, address) {
    console.log("A worker is now connected to " + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

cluster.on('disconnect', function (worker) {
    console.log('The worker #' + worker.id + ' has disconnected');
});

cluster.on('online', function (worker) {
    console.log("The worker responded after it was forked worker ID ::" + worker.id);
});
```

Redisconnection Utilty

```
var redis = require('redis'),
config = require('../resource/config.js');
var RedisConnection = function () {
    this.client = redis.createClient(config.rDisServer.port,config.rDisServer.host);
    this.getClient = function () {
        this.client.select(config.rDisServer.dbname);
        return this.client;
    };
    this.client.on("error", function (err) { 
        console.log("Redis connection error to " + this.client.host + ":" + this.client.port + " - " + err); 
     }); 

    this.quit = function () {
        return this.client.quit();
    };
}

module.exports = RedisConnection;
```

Comment: Have you tried this with node v0.10.28?

Comment: yes thats one of the planned movements , cant do that quickly since thr are some approvals , buts is there a major change btw these two version that we will have these performance issues